# Adding contacts to list view?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, contacts, android-2.2-froyo

I have a ListView and I have a contact picker. What I want to do is when I pick a contact I want the contact to show up in a list view and be saved in that list view. so far I have

```
ListView emailEntry = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);  
                  emailEntry.setFilterText(Number);  
                  if (Number.length() == 0) {  
                      Toast.makeText(this, "No number found for contact.",  
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                  }
```

This is the Java text were the number gets called into the list view

```
<ListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/list"
/>
```

this is obviously my .XML file.

I get no force closing. the problem is the contact doesn't get called into the list view

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information about what you are trying to do? What is your data source?

I have never used ListView. As a consequence, I probably missed the point but here is my two cents.
Based on my humble assumptions, why don't you use a ListActivity and a custom (List)Adapter to display your data? Then you could implement onListItemClick() and use startActivity() (with the proper intent) or fire a toast or whatever is usefull. My opinion is that your problem is a data-centric problem, not a view-centric one.

Best Regards,
Renaud